# How to end a dashed border after text instead of extending across the page in the right direction?

Tags: html, css, border

[Dashed border (screenshot and preferred ending point)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3MBe.png)

As you can see, the border extends towards the end of the page, when I'd rather have it end right after the text ends.. (almost). Is there a specific way to do this?
p.s. I want it to only be this way for this ONE heading, not for anything else.

Here is my code:

```html
<h1 style="border-style:dashed;border-left-width:2px;border-right-width:2px;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"><b><u>Current Projects (in order of importance):</b></u></h1>
<p><ol>
 <li>Apartment Life Redux</li>
 <li>Sharpshooter Infinite</li>
</ol></p>
```

Comment: your `span` or `div` is probably `display:block` try `display:inline-block`

Comment: Add your html and css please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `display:inline;` and rest of the thing will be fine.

```html
<h1 style="border-style:dashed;border-left-width:2px;border-right-width:2px;border-width:2px;border-color:black; display:inline;"><b><u>Current Projects (in order of importance):</b></u></h1>
<p><ol>
 <li>Apartment Life Redux</li>
 <li>Sharpshooter Infinite</li>
</ol></p>
```

In case you want to set property only for specific element, you can use the element id like.

```
<div id="foo"><div> //this is in your html
#foo{display:inline;//other styles} //this is part of your css file
```

Hope it was helpful

Comment: @DylanWiles in case it helped you, please upvote the answer so that other can also find it easily

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code snippet that will help you with your problem.

I added `display: inline-block` and then it ends right after your text.

Like this:

```css
.dashed-border {
  border-style:dashed;
  border-left-width:2px;
  border-right-width:2px;
  border-width:2px;
  border-color:black;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="dashed-border"><b><u>Current Projects (in order of importance):</b></u></h1>
<p><ol>
 <li>Apartment Life Redux</li>
 <li>Sharpshooter Infinite</li>
</ol></p>
```

Comment: I added my code and put a post-script message in my op. Please read it and revise your snippet, as it isn't helping me, in my case. (I'm really new to web design.)

Comment: I don't think I understand your question correctly then. You are saying: "the border extends towards the end of the page, when I'd rather have it end right after the text ends" and now you have updated your code and the border is ending just after your text?

Comment: I want the border of the text to end right after the text, but I want this to be a one-time only case. The code you gave me would have made it so everytime I use the tag <div> and <p>, it would have been underlined, and had a border.